# Updating Maven Project in eclipse

Tags: android

I imported one maven project to eclipse while cleaning the project i get getting this error

An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/project/ProjectHelper

can any one help me to fix this